# How to check a column values is null or not in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server, and I want to validate whether a column value is NULL or empty in the select statement .

The select statement is :

```
SELECT COM_TYPE, COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION 
FROM TABLE_01
```

If the `COM_TYPE` value is null or empty, I want to take the `COM_TYPE_OTHERS` value as `COM_TYPE` for the same way to `COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION`.

It's simply if the COM_TYPE and COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION is null or empty I want to take the values from other two columns.

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: Note that accepted answer does not check for empty strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me assume that blank is `NULL`.  In that case, you simply want `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(COM_TYPE, COM_TYPE_OTHERS, COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION, COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION_OTHERS) as effective_COM_TYPE
```

The `coalesce()` function takes the first non-`NULL` argument.  If the values could be empty strings or strings with spaces in addition to `NULL`, then a `case` expression is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

`COALESCE` function can check which one column is first non-NULL, but you, if you want to check, is `null` or empty you can try to use `CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN COM_TYPE IS NULL OR COM_TYPE = '' THEN COM_TYPE_OTHERS 
             ELSE COM_TYPE END AS COM_TYPE,
        CASE WHEN COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION IS NULL OR COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION = '' THEN COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION_OTHERS 
             ELSE COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION END AS COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION,
FROM TABLE_01
```

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way to check for null or empty is to use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(COM_TYPE, ''), COM_TYPE_OTHERS)
FROM TABLE_01
```

You can also use [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) but it does not check for empty string (only null), so you will still have to use `NULLIF`.

Also note that `ISNULL` is faster than `COALESCE` even if the difference is pretty negligible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` OR `CASE WHEN` statement

```
SELECT COALESCE( COM_TYPE, COM_TYPE_OTHERS ) AS COM_TYPE,
       COALESCE (COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION , COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION_OTHERS) AS COM_IN_CHARGE_POSITION 
FROM   TABLE_01
```